# Examples of 10 million plus Elastic clusters?

Tags: elasticsearch

Unless I'm missing an obvious list that's provided somewhere, there doesn't seem to be a list that gives examples of large-ish Elastic clusters.

To answer this question I'd appreciate it if you could list a solution you know of and some brief details about it.  Note that no organisational details need be shared unless these are already public.

**Core info**

- Number of nodes (machines)
- Gb of index size
- Gb of source size
- Number of documents / items (millions)
- When the system was built (year)

*Any of the follow information would be appreciated as well:*

- Node layout / Gb of memory in each node.  Number of master nodes (generally smaller), number and layout of data nodes
- Ingest and / or query performance (docs per second, queries per second)
- Types of CPU - num cores, year of manufacture or actual CPU specifics
- Any other relevant information or suggestions of types of additional info to request

And as always - many thanks for this, and I hope it helps all of us !

Answer (score 0):

- 24 m4.2xlarge for data nodes,
- separate masters and monitoring cluster
- multiple indices (~30 per day), 1-2Tb of data per day
- 700-1000M documents per day
- It is continiously building, changing, optimizing (since version 1.4)
- hundreds of search requests per second, 10-30k documents per second